# Ping a website address to return an IP

Tags: python

Hey, i'm new to python programing and i have problem that i can't decifer the answer to though a google search.

I need to ping a website address (eg www.google.com) and have python return me a IP address.

Cheers

Comment: You definitly want a DNS lookup. See the answer by @Sandro Munda.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you want to do a "DNS lookup"  :

```
import socket
print socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
```

Output:

```
74.125.230.112
```

EDIT:

For IPv6 support, you can use [getaddrinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo)(). However, I'm not sure that is what you want ;)

Comment: cheers man, would have thought an answer that simple would have been easy to find lol

Comment: sure thing, works like a charm, apparently i have to wait 6 mins though

Comment: @kurimi Yeah, but I don't think that is Jarred wants. I have edit my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do an NS lookup?

```
>>> import socket
>>> print socket.getaddrinfo('www.google.com', 80)
```

@Jarred, gethostbyname() as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html), does not support IPv6. Also if you look at the result of `getaddrinfo()`, there are other ip addresses related to "www.google.com".

Comment: whats the differnace between this and the previous answer?

Comment: is there any disadvantage to using getaddrinfo()?

Comment: For your case, no. Not that I know of.